# SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function percentile_agg(double precision) does not exist for timescaleDB

Tags: timescaledb

i’m following this https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/tutorials/nfl-analytics/advanced-analysis/#average-and-median-yards-run-per-game-by-type-of-player  , for this sql, i got the error:

```
WITH sum_yards AS (
 SELECT a.player_id, displayname, SUM(yards) AS yards, gameid
 FROM player_yards_by_game a
 LEFT JOIN player p ON a.player_id = p.player_id
 GROUP BY a.player_id, displayname, gameid
)
SELECT player_id, displayname, mean(percentile_agg(yards)) as yards
FROM sum_yards
GROUP BY player_id, displayname
ORDER BY yards DESC
```

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function percentile_agg(double precision)
> does not exist   Hint: No function matches the given name and argument
> types. You might need to add explicit type casts.   Position: 246

I have followed the tutorial this far without any error... but this error suddenly pop out... Anyone helps? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you don't have the TimescaleDB Toolkit extension installed, https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/install-timescaledb-toolkit/. Depending on how you're running Timescale, it may be just as easy as `CREATE EXTENSION timescaledb_toolkit;` Otherwise, you may need to build the extension and install via the instructions here: https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-toolkit/blob/main/Readme.md

Answer (score 0):

When I run `CREATE EXTENSION timescaledb_toolkit;` the result is`ERROR:  could not access file "MODULE_PATHNAME": No such file or directory`. I just reinstalled or confirmed install following the instructions for [installing with the Postgres.app on Apple Silicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73248119/how-do-you-install-timescaledb-on-mac-os-m1-apple-silicone-if-you-have-the-pos)