# How do you install timescaledb on MAC OS M1 (apple Silicone) if you have the postgress.app installed

Tags: timescaledb

Edit: I know it’s easier using homebrew if you have postgres installed via homebrew, but i wanted to keep my Postgress.app setup for other reasons

How do you install timescaledb on Apple Sillicone M1 Chip?

I am getting this error

```
tsdb=# CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/14/share/postgresql/extension/timescaledb.control": No such file or directory
```

After following instructions on

https://docs.timescale.com/install/latest/self-hosted/installation-macos/#install-self-hosted-timescaledb-using-homebrew

Comment: [I recommend instaling PostgreSQL and Timeescaledb through Homebrew on Mac](https://brew.sh/) as it is a bit easier.

Comment: I know it’s easier using homebrew if you have postgres installed via homebrew, but i wanted to keep my Postgress.app setup for other reasons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question was not on Stack Overflow So I decided to ask it and answer it

## Step 1: Make sure you have the latest postgress.app installed

You need to have at least postgres v14 of the postgress.app, if you dont you will get this error

```
ld: can't link with a main executable file '/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/13/bin/postgres' for architecture arm64
```

because older versions used only intel

## Step 2: Follow the instructions for homebrew

Use the instructions [here](https://docs.timescale.com/install/latest/self-hosted/installation-macos/#install-self-hosted-timescaledb-using-homebrew)

but when you get to this step `timescaledb-tune --quiet --yes` you start following my isntructions

## Step 3: My instructions

### step 3.1

Since the homebrew method expects to use homebrew postgres you have to point the tune command to postgress.app config file instead by running this

`timescaledb-tune --yes --conf-path="/Users/tawanda/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-14/postgresql.conf"`

replace `var-14` with your version of postgres if later

### step 3.2

manually run your own setup as below because the script that comes with timescale wont work for your posgresss.app use case

```
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 $(find /opt/homebrew/Cellar/timescaledb/2.7.2/lib/timescaledb/postgresql/ -name "timescaledb*.so")  /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/14/lib/postgresql

/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/timescaledb/2.7.2/share/timescaledb/* /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/14/share/postgresql/extension/
```

replace version 14 and version 2.7.2 with your postgress and timescale versions respectively if later

### step3.3

initialise the extension

```
tawanda=# CREATE database tsdb;
    
tawanda=# \c tsdb;

tsdb=# CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb;
WARNING:
WELCOME TO
 _____ _                               _     ____________
|_   _(_)                             | |    |  _  \ ___ \
  | |  _ _ __ ___   ___  ___  ___ __ _| | ___| | | | |_/ /
  | | | |  _ ` _ \ / _ \/ __|/ __/ _` | |/ _ \ | | | ___ \
  | | | | | | | | |  __/\__ \ (_| (_| | |  __/ |/ /| |_/ /
  |_| |_|_| |_| |_|\___||___/\___\__,_|_|\___|___/ \____/
               Running version 2.7.2
For more information on TimescaleDB, please visit the following links:

 1. Getting started: https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/getting-started
 2. API reference documentation: https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest
 3. How TimescaleDB is designed: https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/overview/core-concepts

Note: TimescaleDB collects anonymous reports to better understand and assist our users.
For more information and how to disable, please see our docs https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/configuration/telemetry.

CREATE EXTENSION
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing in detail your solution for this. It's a question we get asked quite often (I'm Timescale's community manager) and we often suggest docker on Mac. This seems a useful alternative, so thank you. Are you OK if I post a link to this on our forum?

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes please do share, happy to contribute in this small way. Thanks for making such an awesome extension

Comment: @greenweeds Can you update the entire process on https://docs.timescale.com/install/latest/self-hosted/installation-macos/#set-up-the-timescaledb-extension

Comment: @DrManhattan For step 3.1, i somehow dont have Postgress folder in Users/<myname>/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-14/postgresql.conf.
Can you assist what could be the reason. I followed everything from the main timescale link until your step mentioned.

Comment: @asimo firstly any relation with Honda's Asimo. Next 2 questions 1) are you using the postgress.app installation the one you drag/install into your application folder 2) are you using version 14 postgress

Comment: @DrManhattan Hi Dr :) Thank you for your reply; Indeed I was a big fan when Honda's asimo back in the days, and hence the name.
@ the issue, i had used homebrew to get to the process.
And yes it version 14 
And my postgresql.conf is in /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14

Comment: Hi @asimo then we have diagnosed the problem. the instructions above are only valid for when you install postgress using the mac app. If you used homebrew then try the official docs on Timescales website. PS: also a serious Asimo fan, sucks that Honda canned the project

Comment: Thanks again @DrManhattan for the reply. Strange enough but following the timescale docs/website info has been giving error at the same step. I'll double check everything again. :(

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution I use is to run timescaledb in docker, specifically with docker compose. This allows you to keep all your data in a docker volume so you can move your DB from computer to computer and also set the ports, passwords, etc. from your `docker-compose.yml` file.

Here is the `docker-compose.yml` file I use to run my local timescaledb instance:

```
version: "3"

# special port for timescaledb: 5445
services:
  timescaledb:
    image: timescale/timescaledb:latest-pg14
    ports:
      - "5445:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./timescaledb-data
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "1000k"
        max-file: "5"
        compress: "true"
```

**NOTE**: I map the timescaledb port to 5445 because I also have postgres running on my system. This allows me to keep postgres running for other applications that require it while still accessing timescaledb.

Answer (score 0):

@DrManhattan. Thank you for your detailed instructions. Even a year later, the official instructions are confusing. Easy to get lost in the ifs (Brew, self-hosted, etc). Also confusing is macOS system level, Postgres, and the Rails app I'm working on. I originally was confused where to run the commands. But decided that at macOS root made the most sense.

Minor notes to those following this: Step 3.3 is in psql which you get to with `psql` on the command line or probably can do in PGAdmin.

Like the OP I wanted to continue with the app rather than Homebrew which I prefer for most uses. Will look into Docker if I keep having issues.

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad it's still useful even a year later